# How to include files for a project in a different directory

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

[image]

I clearly added AFNetworking by reference (notice the blue color of the folder).

Yet, xcode complain that there is no such file called AFNetworking.h

I included the folder rather than the file actually

Comment: clean your project and build it again...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Xcode's folder reference for code. It's primarily used for resources. To be able to compile your code, add AFNetworking file as a group instead.

Comment: What does it mean by add AFNetworking file as a group? I do not want to copy the source code.